# Rotate Strip Text in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet-wrap

I'm having a hard time figuring out how to rotate the `strip.text` attribute in `theme` from `ggplot2`. I'm using R version 3.4.2 and ggplot2 version 2.2.1.

Below is the data for the MWE.

```
> dput(dd)
structure(list(type = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L), .Label = c("blossum", 
"happy", "rugged", "theatre"), class = "factor"), min = c(3, 
2, 4, 6, 3, 2, 4, 6, 3, 2, 4, 6, 3, 2, 4, 6, 3, 2, 4, 6), max = c(8, 
3, 7, 9, 8, 3, 7, 9, 8, 3, 7, 9, 8, 3, 7, 9, 8, 3, 7, 9), avg = c(5, 
1, 3, 3, 5, 1, 3, 3, 5, 1, 3, 3, 5, 1, 3, 3, 5, 1, 3, 3), y = c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L)), .Names = c("type", "min", "max", "avg", "y"), row.names = c(NA, 
20L), class = "data.frame")
```

Now when using the `element_text()` attribute, I can color the `strip.text` but cannot get the angle to change. I want the strip (facet) names to run horizontally on the left. Here is the code:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(dd, aes(x = y, ymin = min, ymax = max, y = avg)) +
  facet_wrap(~ type, ncol = 1, strip.position = "left") +
  geom_ribbon(aes(x = y, ymin = min, ymax = max),
              color='black', fill='gray70') + coord_flip() +
  theme(strip.background = element_blank(),
        strip.text = element_text(angle=90, color='blue4'),
        axis.title.y = element_blank(),
        axis.text.y = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.y = element_blank(),
        axis.line.y = element_blank())
```

And that produces this graph:
[image: picture of the graph]

However, this is not what I am wanting, as their is no difference when the angle is changed in `strip.text = element_blank(angle=90, color='blue4')`.

Comment: In `ggplot2` version `3.3.2`, and R `3.6.2`, the answer above no-longer works for me. The argument: `strip.text.y` must be replaced with `strip.text.y.left`, and the angle argument is no longer offset by 180 degrees. This question is also very similar to this question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40484090/rotate-switched-facet-labels-in-ggplot2-facet-grid I'm unable to post this as a comment due to low reputation.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Nevermind I figured it out by using `strip.text.y = element_text(angle = 180)`. Not sure why `strip.text` alone does not work.

Comment: This answser does not work any more. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/73800776/8806649

Answer (score 11):

Use `strip.text.y.left` now.
Add `angle = 0` as an argument.

```r
ggplot(dd, aes(x = y, ymin = min, ymax = max, y = avg)) +
  facet_wrap(~ type, ncol = 1, strip.position = "left") +
  geom_ribbon(aes(x = y, ymin = min, ymax = max),
              color='black', fill='gray70') + coord_flip() +
  theme(
    strip.background = element_blank(),
    strip.text.y.left = element_text(angle = 0, color = 'blue4'), #THE LINE THAT IS EDITED
    axis.title.y = element_blank(),
    axis.text.y = element_blank(),
    axis.ticks.y = element_blank(),
    axis.line.y = element_blank())
```

[image]

Answer taken from [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48892826/rotate-strip-text-in-ggplot2?noredirect=1&lq=1#comment114015613_48892826)

Answer (score 1):

```
ggplot(dd, aes(x = y, ymin = min, ymax = max, y = avg)) +
  facet_wrap(~ type, ncol = 1, strip.position = "left") +
  geom_ribbon(aes(x = y, ymin = min, ymax = max),
    color='black', fill='gray70') + coord_flip() + 
  theme(strip.background = element_blank(),
    strip.text.y = element_text(angle=180, color='blue4'),
    axis.title.y = element_blank(),
    axis.text.y = element_blank(),
    axis.ticks.y = element_blank(),
    axis.line.y = element_blank()
  )
```

Comment: This answser does not work any more. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/73800776/8806649